# Inserting default values in slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, insert, default, slick

I have the following class that represents a record in postgresql:

```
case class Action(id: Option[Int], EmailAct: String, carriedAt: Timestamp)
```

`id` is an auto-increment field and `carriedAt` defaults to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. How do I tell Slick I only want to provide value for `EmailAct` and the rest should be defaults?

This does not quite work: `Dbs.actionsLog += Action(null, "test", null)` - `id` gets auto-incremented but `carriedAt` becomes empty, not default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

insert into a query that selects what you want to update:

```
Dbs.actionsLog.map(_.EmailAct) += "test"
```

Comment: This works but I don't understand exactly how. Just out of curiosity, does this still generate a simple INSERT query or is an UPDATE evolved here?

Comment: A single INSERT. And why it works: in inserts and in normal queries, you both select which columns you mean (i.e. insert into or return), only that in SQL the syntax is different for these cases. In Slick the syntax is the same. You just write a query that selects what you need but instead of running the query you insert into it. It can look confusing at first but once you see it, it is quite elegant.

Comment: It is indeed. Thanks for explanations.